# Kubernetes Privileged Containers and Capabilities

Tags: google-chrome, docker, kubernetes

I have a container with some SYS_ADMIN capabilities, and I'm having trouble killing the pod, and am wondering what is the best way to deal with these reluctant containers?

```
- image: headless-chrome
  securityContext:
   capabilities:
     add:
     - SYS_ADMIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a pod will zombify, even without privileged status. In order to kill a zombified pod, first try the following:

     `kubectl delete pod <<PODNAME>> --grace-period=0 --force`

...where `<<PODNAME>>` is the name of the offending pod. I have to do that from time to time, even with v1.7.X.

If that doesn't work, then try to first `kubectl drain` the node, find the Docker container (`docker ps`), delete it (`docker rm`), restart the Docker service and the Kubelet service, then `kubectl uncordon` the node. I've only had to do that once, and not since v1.6.X.